# Is every simply connected Kähler manifold homogeneous?

Tags: complex-analysis, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Does every connected simply connected Kähler manifold admit a transitive action by a Lie group?

Comment: Isn't a $K3$ surface a counterexample?

Comment: Either Kähler or Kaehler is a correct spelling (they are essentially the same). If it were Kahler it would be pronounced differently.

Comment: Sorry about the spelling!

Comment: @Jason DeVito K3 surface sounds like a great counterexample! Why can’t a K3 surface admit a transitive action by a Lie group?

Comment: @MichaelHardy I believe everybody deserves his name spelled correctly, and so does Erich Kähler (with the German umlaut "ä"). But nevertheless I would say "Kaehler" is acceptable, historically the "ä" originated from "ae". Even in Germany older typewriters didn't have an "ä" and so people used "ae".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not a complex geometer, but if you can believe Wikipedia, then the (a?) $K3$ surface is not homogeneous for any action of a (finite dimensional) Lie group.  I will sketch the most elementary proof I know below.

First, topologically, $K3$ is a closed simply connected $4$-manifold with second Betti number $b_2(K3) = 22$.

Let us suppose for a contradiction that there is some Lie group $G$ which acts transitively on $K3$.  By modding out by the ineffective kernel, we may assume the action is effective.  Because $K3$ is connected, the identity component of $G$ acts transitively, so we may as well assume $G$ is connected.  Further, because $K3$ is compact and simply connected, [a theorem of Montgomery](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1950-001-04/S0002-9939-1950-0037311-6/S0002-9939-1950-0037311-6.pdf) implies that the maximal compact subgroup of $G$ acts transitively.  In particular, we may assume $G$ is compact.  Now this implies we can find a Riemannian metric on $K3$ for which the $G$ action is isometric.

Let $H$ denote the isotropy group at some point $p\in K3$.  Since $H$ fixes $p$, it acts (effectively) on the set of unit vectors in $T_p K3$, so we may view $H\subseteq O(4)$. Thus, $H$ has rank at most $2$.

Also, we get a long exact sequence $\rightarrow...\pi_2(H)\rightarrow \pi_2(G)\rightarrow \pi_2(K3)\rightarrow \pi_1(H)\rightarrow \pi_1(G)\rightarrow 0$.

Since $\pi_2$ of any Lie group vanishes, $\pi_2(K3)$ must inject into $\pi_1(H)$.  But, from the Hurewicz theorem, $\pi_2(K3)\cong H_2(K3)\cong \mathbb{Z}^{22}$, so $\mathbb{Z}^{22}\subseteq \pi_1(H)$.

This implies that $H$ has a finite cover of the form $H_0\times T^k$ with $k\geq 22$ (and $H_0$ simply connected).  In particular, the rank of $H$ is at least $22$.

Since we already know the rank is at most $2$, we have a contradiction.

(In particular, this proof shows that a simply connected closed $4$-manifold which is homogeneous must have $b_2 \leq 2$.)

Comment: This proof also generalizes to give the following:  if $M^n$ is a closed simply connected manifold with rational Betti number $b_2(M)> \frac{n}{2}$, then $M$ cannot be homogeneous.  This is sharp in even dimensions: a product of any number of $S^2$s is homogeneous, and has $b_2(M) = \frac{n}{2}$.  In odd dimensions, one can actually do better:  if $\dim M = 2n +1$, and $b_2(M) > n - 1$, then $M$ cannot be homogeneous.  The proof I know uses rational homotopy theory.  This result is also sharp:  $S^3$ times a product of $S^2$s achieves the equality case.